# rails app select_tag's selected value persisting (I don't want it to)

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, html-select

Inside a partial in one of my views, I've got a simple form_tag helper with two select_tag fields, both of which have default values:

```
<%= form_tag(some_models_index_path, method: "get", id: "chart-form", remote: true) do %>
  <%= select_tag "duration", options_for_select(2..60, 12), :selected => 12 %>
  <%= select_tag "unit", options_for_select([ "months", "weeks" ], "months") %>
  <%= submit_tag "update view", name: nil %>
<% end %>
```

There is another partial showing this data that is set up to default to 12 months of data, and my form uses Ajax to update that partial. Everything works normally, except that if I select a new value on either input, navigate to another page, and then return, the inputs do not revert to the default values. This is true whether I submitted the form before navigating away or not. I tried going into development.rb and production.rb and turning off page caching, but that did not solve the problem, and that's probably a bad idea anyway. Is there a helper parameter or html attribute that I'm missing here? Thanks.

Comment: I think this might be the browsers default behaviour and not due to server side caching.

Answer (score 0):

Turning my form autocomplete attribute off solved the problem.

```
<%= form_tag(baskets_path, method: "get", id: "chart-form", remote: true, :autocomplete => "off") do %>
```